# Display JavaScript values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

How to solve this on second picture, suppose to be the value of 3 on column USD and the others don't have value suppose to be zero.

```
<div class="span3">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" >
        <?php
        foreach ( $submenu as $sm ) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$base_url.$sm['link'].'">'.$sm['title'].'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>    
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add New Daily Price Index</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="myForm" method="post">

          <div class="span2">Index</div>
          <input type="text" name="indexval" id="indexval"/>
          <!--input type="hidden" value="hello" id="myField"-->

            <!--button id="myFormSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button-->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="myFormSubmit" >Save</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <section id="global">
    <legend><h4><?=$title?> <small>( Admin )</small></h4></legend>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">Search By</div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" id="r1"  name="someRadioGroup" value="daily"/> Daily
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" id="r2"  name="someRadioGroup" value="monthly"/> Monthly    
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="output">
            <div id="daily">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <div class="span2">Date: </div>
                From&nbsp;
                        <input type="text" id="sdate" name="sdate" value="<?=$sdate?>" class="input-small"><span class="add-on">&nbsp;&nbsp; to &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        <input type="text" id="edate" name="edate" value="<?=$edate?>" class="input-small"> 
                <hr>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2"></div>
                <div class="span10">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button id="btn_display_daily" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i>&nbsp;Display</button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i>Add New</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="month">
        <div class="span2">Billing </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Month&nbsp;
             <select name="month" class="span2" id="month">
                <?php
                $billing_start = $def_date_man_start;
                $billing_start = date_parse($billing_start);
                for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
                    $time_tmp = mktime (0, 0, 0, $x+1 , 0, 0);
                    $month = date('F',$time_tmp);
                    $sel = (($billing_start['month']) == $x) ? 'selected=selected' : '';
                    echo '<option value="'.$x.'" '.$sel.' >'.$month .'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Year&nbsp;
            <select name="year" class="span2" id="year">
                <?php
                for($x=2006;$x<=date('Y')+5;$x++){
                    $sel = ($billing_start['year'] == $x) ? 'selected=selected' : '';
                    echo '<option value="'.$x.'" '.$sel.' >'.$x.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        <hr>
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span10">
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="btn_display_records" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i>&nbsp;Display</button>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button id="btn_display_records" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i>&nbsp;Add New</button>
        </div>
         </div>


        </div>

    </div>
<div id="indexresult"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</div>
<!--div id="output2"></div-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$.extend({
 loadDailyData : function () {
        $('#result').html('');
        $("#result").html('Getting Data.... &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        var daily   = $('#r1').val();
        $.post('../billing/daily_index_process',{sdate:$('#sdate').val(),edate:$('#edate').val(),'daily':daily},



            function(data){
                //console.log(data)
                $('#result').html('');
                  var date = "<table class='table'><tr><td>Date</td>"
                    $.each(data.value, function (delivery_date, val1){

                    $.each(val1, function (x,v){

                      date += "<td>"+v.indexval+"</td>";
                    })
                    })
                    date +="<tr>"

                  $.each(data.value, function (delivery_date, val1){
                   var dd =delivery_date ; 

                   date +="<td>"+dd+"</td>"


                   $.each(val1, function (x,v){

                    //date += "<td>"+v.priceval+"</td>";
                    date += "<td>"+v.priceval+"</td>";
                   })
                    date +="<tr>"
                  //console.log(delivery_date)
                    $('#result').html(date); 
                  })


                }

        );
    }

})


</script>
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#month").hide();
        $("#daily").hide();
        $('#sdate, #edate').datepicker();
    $("input[name=someRadioGroup]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#r1").attr("checked")) {
            $('#result').html('');
            $("#month").hide();
            $("#daily").show();        
        }
        else{
        $('#result').html('');
          $("#month").show();
          $("#daily").hide();
        }
    })
});
</script>
<script>
function jsFunction(){
    $( "#sdate, #edate" ).datepicker( "show" );
}
</script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#myFormSubmit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var daily     = $('#r1').val();
      var indexval  = $('#indexval').val();
      var sdate     = $('#sdate').val(); 
      post_data = {'sdate':sdate,'indexval':indexval,'daily':daily};
          $.post('<?=$base_url?>/billing/add_index_process',post_data,
        function(data){

            alert(data)
            window.parent.location.reload();

        }
        )
    });
});
</script>
<script>
    $('#btn_display_daily').unbind('click').bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.loadDailyData();
});
</script>
```

pic 1
http://s1323.photobucket.com/user/Paul_Yuki/media/problem_zpse6067419.png.html?filters[user]=134917646&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

pic 2
http://s1323.photobucket.com/user/Paul_Yuki/media/problem2_zps747b33bd.png.html?filters[user]=134917646&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1

Here's my query:

```
select type,indexval,delivery_date,priceval from price_indices
where delivery_date between '$sdate' and '$edate' and `type`='$type'
order by delivery_date
```

Answer (score 1):

To use php value in javascript. Store php value in a variable and then echo in javascript. example:-

```
$value=3;//store value

$('#div').html('<?php echo $value ?>');//show php value
```